# Writing to MySQL using Python is not working?

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have this simple code for writing data to MySQL database.

```
mycursor = sql_db.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO users (discord_id, platform, gamertag) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
val = (interaction.user.id, platform.value, gamertag)

print(val)

try:
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    sql_db.commit

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(err)
    print("Error Code:", err.errno)
    print("SQLSTATE:", err.sqlstate)
    print("Message:", err.msg)

mycursor.close
sql_db.close

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

MySQL server is hosted on VPS server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OigaP.png)

Console output is:

```
(176432554692313088, 'acti', 'jcK_#2039728')
1 record inserted.
```

Looks like writing was successful, but my database is still empty. Any idea what is happening or how to catch error to find out why my data are not writing to database?

I tried catch errors with this except but as you can see, it doesn't catch anything.

```
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(err)
    print("Error Code:", err.errno)
    print("SQLSTATE:", err.sqlstate)
    print("Message:", err.msg)
```

Comment: you need to do `sql_db.commit()`. You are instead doing `sql_db.commit` which won't call the method

Comment: The same with `mycursor.close` and `sql_db.close`. Should be `mycursor.close()` and `sql_db.close()`.

Comment: oh my god, you right!  I was trying to find solution for 3 hours. I feel so stupid.. Thanks a lot